# Workflow control in mysql or oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, t-sql

In Mssql, you can submit batch query statements with workflow control, like this:

```
DECLARE @Num INT
SELECT @Num = 100
IF @Num > 0
BEGIN
SELECT @Num = @Num + 1
END
```

how could I do this in MySql or Oracle (without procedure or function).

Comment: What "workflow control" are you implementing?  You can create an anonymous PL/SQL block in Oracle if you just want to implement some procedural logic.

Comment: general workflow, like:'if else', 'while' and local variable declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `IF ... THEN` in official MySQL outside of stored programs.

You can, however, do it in MySQL-compatible MariaDB, starting in version 10.1 (currently in beta).

> Now one can use `BEGIN`, `IF`, `CASE`, `WHILE`, `LOOP`, `REPEAT` statements directly in SQL scripts and from the mysql command line prompt — outside of stored programs.
>
> https://blog.mariadb.org/mariadb-10-1-1-compound-statements/